# Cast on ArrayList generics

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

I have two classes A and B, both them extend a class C.
Now, class D has two ArrayLists as members:

- ArrayList< A > (said `arrayA`)
- ArrayList< B > (said `arrayB`)

D has also a method that returns either arrayA or arrayB, but I would like to convert them in an `ArrayList< C >`, so I don't have to worry about discern whether it returns `arrayA` or `arrayB`.

I know that `ArrayList< A >` and `ArrayList< B >` don't extend `ArrayList< C >` (even if A and B extend C), but how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `ArrayList<? extends C>` from that method of class `D`.

***Edit:***

You need to cast the returned value to the expected type and you will get the waring of unsafe type casting operation. And this is unavoidable.

Comment: Yea, Had better luck this time... :P You know, you always beat me like this way.. :D

Comment: I thought it, but it "doesn't work". I mean I have to explicitly cast the returned type in ArrayList< C > and I have a warning of type unsafe.

Comment: Yes of course. Here is how I call the function:
ArrayList<C> list = (ArrayList<C>) r.getList(which);
And here is the warning
Type safety: Unchecked cast from ArrayList<capture#4-of ? extends C> to ArrayList<C>

Comment: I know it's just a warning but... I would like to remove it :)

Comment: @DanieleVitali If you're just reading from the returned list then just leave it typed as `List<? extends C>` without casting it.

Comment: Or `new ArrayList<C>(list)`.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). Here is an example:

```
class C {
}

class A extends C {
}

class B extends C {
}

class D {
    private ArrayList<A> aList;
    private ArrayList<B> bList;

    public ArrayList<? extends C> getList(boolean aOrB) {
        return aOrB ? aList : bList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have 1 `List` that has `ArrayList<C>` and a method that returns a `List<C>`.

That way, you can `add(C element)` which can be either `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type in Class D as

```
ArrayList<? extends C>
```